# How to create a jwt image within a spring controller

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Hey,
     I have a spring controller as shown below which is there to create certain image.

```
public class ImageMapController extends AbstractController {


protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal( HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response ) throws Exception
        {
            File file = new File("C:/Users/Rahul/Pictures/EmptyParkingLot.jpg");

            BufferedImage image= javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(file);
            int width = image.getWidth();
            int height = image.getHeight();
            BufferedImage buffer =
                new BufferedImage(width*2,
                                  height,
                                  BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics g=buffer.getGraphics();
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
            g2.setBackground(Color.white);
            g2.setColor(Color.red);
            g2.drawString("Item 1",0,0);

            g2.drawImage(image, 40, 40, null);
            g2.drawString("Item 2",width,0);
            g2.drawImage(image, 40 + width, 40, null);

            ServletOutputStream out1 = response.getOutputStream();
            JPEGImageEncoder encoder= JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out1);
            encoder.encode(buffer);

            return new ModelAndView("parkingimage");
        }
```

}

The above code works really fine and it displays the image I want in parkingimage.jsp. But as opposed to flushing it out as jsp I just want to use it as an image within my jsp with `<img>`tag OR how do I include this jsp within another jsp as apart from displaying the image I have some text that I want to display in the same jsp I'm displaying the image.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Serotonin Chase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create another controller to generate a page, and `<img src = "...">` in that page should point to the controller that generates images (these URLs can contain parameters if needed).

Another option is to use [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), but it has limited size and browser support.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried <img src = ".."> on another jsp and it works perfectly fine.